# PHP calendar display previews and next button

Tags: php, calendar

I have a code that display only mondays of the month.

how do I input next and previous month button using the code below.

```
$startDate  = "2014-08-01";
$endDate = "2014-09-26";


$endDate = strtotime($endDate);
echo '<table border=1>';
echo '<tr>';
for($i = strtotime('Monday', strtotime($startDate)); $i <= $endDate; $i = strtotime('+1 week', $i))

    echo '<td>'.date('d-M-y', $i).'</td>';   

echo '</tr>';   
echo '</table>';
```

this is the output of the code

```
04-Aug-14   11-Aug-14   18-Aug-14   25-Aug-14   01-Sep-14   08-Sep-14   15-Sep-14   22-Sep-14
```

Comment: What exactly would the 'next' and 'previous' buttons do?

Comment: next month and previous month